# SQL Command - UPDATE with Inner Join

Tags: sql

I have tree tables:

Table A: ID(PK), X, Y

Table B: ID(Not PK), CID

Table C: ID(PK), X, Y

and   (B.ID = C.ID)
and ---Condition---> `A.X = C.X And A.Y = C.Y`

how can i set B.CID = C.ID?

Comment: which flavour of sql are you using? (e.g. mysql, MS sql server, postgres)?

Comment: Add some sample data, and wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE B
SET CID = C.ID
FROM dbo.TableA A
JOIN dbo.TableC C ON A.X = C.X AND A.Y = C.Y
JOIN dbo.TableB B ON B.ID = C.ID
```